# In C#, when does execution of an async method resume after await, while the calling method is still running?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

When I call an async method that then awaits something, after the await is completed, what has to happen in the calling method for the execution of the async method to resume?

For example, I tested the code below and it seems to never finish (I forced stopped it after a few minutes). So it seems execution of `DoAsync` doesn't resume as long as the `Test` method is stuck in that loop. I assume something needs to happen for it to resume, but I am unsure as to what that something is.

Note: I'm using Unity, so maybe it doesn't hang using a console or windows application.

Note2: I know my code is not useful and that's not how you'd use async. It's only an experiment in which I'm trying to figure out what goes on under the hood.

```
class TestClass {

    bool finished = false;      

    void Test()
    {
        DoAsync();
        while (!finished) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
                bb++;
            }
        }
    }

    async void DoAsync() {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/3pJEKb

Comment: what is the scope of `finished`? Are you certain they are referring to the same variable?

Comment: @RobertHarvey strange. Maybe because I'm using Unity?

Comment: @DStanley added the enclosing code, it's a member variable of the class that contains both methods.

Comment: Writing C# code in Unity is quite different from doing the same in .NET proper.

Comment: See example here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0

Comment: The only place you can do `async void` is in event handlers. Otherwise always do `async Task`.

Comment: instead you could use `var task = Task.Run(() =>YourMEthod());` and then wait for `while(!task.IsCompleted){ ... }` ... note though: Why would you want to have such a blocking `while` loop? It freezes your main thread just the same as the task would ... so what would be the purpose in going async here at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I call an async method that then awaits something, after the await is completed, what has to happen in the calling method for the execution of the async method to resume?

Nothing. The calling method doesn't have to do anything special.

However, the `async` method has to continue running *somewhere*, and [that "somewhere" is in a context captured by the `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as explained on my blog). This "context" is usually the `SynchronizationContext` or a thread pool context.

> For example, I tested the code below and it seems to never finish (I forced stopped it after a few minutes). So it seems execution of DoAsync doesn't resume as long as the Test method is stuck in that loop. I assume something needs to happen for it to resume, but I am unsure as to what that something is.

Most likely, you called it from a UI thread. Like other UI platforms, Unity provides a `SynchronizationContext` (check the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` just *before* the `await` and you'll see what it uses to resume execution). UI contexts are one-thread-at-a-time contexts, so in this case the calling method just runs an infinite loop on the UI thread, never allowing the `async` method to complete. This is very similar to a [deadlock described on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The normal pattern for `async` is to [use it "all the way"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#async-all-the-way). This means using `await` instead of running an infinite loop on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Follow up question - the UI thread itself, I assume it also runs some endless loop in which it listens for UI events and such, so how is that different from my loop that's waiting for a bool to turn true? What does the UI code do to relinquish control that I don't? I'm trying to figure out how this system works under the hood.

Comment: @tbkn23 there is no such "loop" on your UI thread (API wise) but rather e.g. an `Update` (+ Render) call each frame .. of course internally it is a loop (and that's why everything will be freezing until your c# loop is done) but on API level you want to either think in frame calls or as mentioned here use the `async` pattern the correct way ;) This said I strongly recommend [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) which provides a lightweight async implementation as well as seamless integretion with the Unity main thread and extenions to await Unity's AsyncOperations (e.g. web request)

Comment: The UI loop is a message processing loop. The only way to schedule code on a UI thread is to send it a message saying "run this code". So that's what the UI `SynchronizationContext` does. Your loop doesn't work because it doesn't process the message queue.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks, it's clear to me now. At first I expected that the OS or .net runtime would automatically switch between the contexts, more or less like it does with threads, but now I realize that async methods are far more synchronous than I thought :)

Comment: @derHugo thanks, yeah I was just trying to figure out how this thing works under the hood, as in - when can the waiting methods resume. It seems to work very similar to co-routines, Unity implemented their own SynchronizationContext in which they process "wait complete" messages, pretty similar to the way they process coroutines.